# Unfold calendar overview?

Tags: html, css

This is how the site looks like today.
[image: This is how the site looks like!]

This is how I want the calendar to unfold!
[image: This is how I want the calendar to unfold!]

I noticed when I press the calendar symbol it pops up a "#" in the end of the URL (like this http://thethief.com/#). And here is some of the code where I found a "#" onclick and the button... But then what?

[image]

Please help?

Comment: do not abuse **bold** and do not post unrelated animated gifs. This is not discussion forum where anyone cares your post footer and animated cats. Focus on **your code** and come back when you face any real problem with **your work**.

Comment: I've taken a look at the web and the calendar unfolds properly. Could you please be more precise on your question (maybe I understood you wrong).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sorry!

Comment: @Hoijof I'd like to unfold the calendar permanently. supersorry for not being too clear. I don't know how to keep the calendar unfolded as in image#2?

Comment: @Hbaecklund Do you mean that you want the calendar to be unfold automatically when you enter the site?

Comment: @Hoijof Yes like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in order to trigger the click event manually and see the calendar unfold at the beginning.

```
$(".date-icon").first().trigger("click")
```